# How to select data that persists over columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains data about mutations with the relevant bits below (0/0 = no mutation, 0/1 = heterozygous mutation, 1/1 = homozygous mutation). In the experiment conducted, we have a treatment given over 5 generations (UV light exposure). I am only interested in mutations that arise and persist over multiple generations (ie, are not lost in time), whether heterozygous (0/1) or homozygous (1/1).

For example, the data in the first row (index 0) should be kept even though it only appears in the last column. Indexed rows 5, 7, 9 and 10 should also be kept as they persist across all generations after appearing.

I'm really lost as to how to start going about this. Maybe a series of if statements could be used while looping through the df, but that isn't very pandorable, is it?

```
index   GEN[0].GT   GEN[1].GT   GEN[2].GT   GEN[3].GT   GEN[4].GT
0   0/0 0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1
1   0/0 0/0 0/1 0/0 0/0
2   0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/0
3   0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/0
4   0/0 0/1 0/0 0/1 0/1
5   0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1 1/1
6   0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 0/0
7   0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
8   0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 0/0
9   0/0 0/0 0/0 1/1 1/1
10  0/0 0/1 0/1 0/1 0/1
```

Comment: so for example, index 8 would not be kept because it goes `0/0 -> 1/1 -> 0/0`? also what about `0/0 -> 1/0 -> 0/1`?

Comment: Thats right! You got it.

Comment: What _exactly_ columns does your dataframe have?

Comment: Columns: [CHROM, POS, REF, ALT, FILTER, GEN[0].GT, GEN[1].GT, GEN[2].GT, GEN[3].GT, GEN[4].GT, ANN[0].EFFECT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As per MattR's observation, I assume that the index column is indeed the index, not a regular column.*

Let's start by replacing the no-mutation markers 0/0 with `np.nan`. When you fill-forward the rows of the new dataframe, the `nan` gaps will be filled with the most recent non-`nan` values:

```
filled = df.replace('0/0', np.nan).fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).fillna("0/0")
```

The filled rows that *do not* differ from the original rows, did not have gaps. Therefore, they did not have 0/0 after non-0/0:

```
good = (filled == df).all(axis=1)
```

And here's their numbers:

```
df[good].index
#Int64Index([0, 5, 7, 9, 10], dtype='int64', name='index')
```

Comment: anyone creating the dataframe with `df = pd.read_clipboard()` will need to remove the `index` column for this to work. run  `del df['index']` and then follow DYZ's example

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I have tried your solution but I am getting an empty dataframe. 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [CHROM, POS, REF, ALT, FILTER, GEN[0].GT, GEN[1].GT, GEN[2].GT, GEN[3].GT, GEN[4].GT, ANN[0].EFFECT]
Index: []
I have not explicitly set an index column. I assumed that a df created without an index will actually create a serialized index behind the scene. Am I missing something?

Comment: Judging by your comment, your dataframe is _different_ from what you mentioned in the question. How do you expect us to give you a right answer to a wrong question?

Comment: I hear you, and I can see how this can be frustrating. My intention was not to waste your time - I am a beginner seeking guidance.

Comment: You can select the columns of interest `df=df[['GEN[0].GT', 'GEN[1].GT', 'GEN[2].GT', 'GEN[3].GT', 'GEN[4].GT']]` and apply the procedure only to them.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, let's try:

```
(df.set_index('index')
  .ne('0/0').astype(int)
  .diff(axis=1).bfill(1)
  .ge(0).all(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
index
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
9      True
10     True
dtype: bool
```

Or to get indexes:

```
s = (df.set_index('index')
      .ne('0/0').astype(int)
      .diff(axis=1).bfill(1)
      .ge(0).all(axis=1))

s[s]

index
0     True
5     True
7     True
9     True
10    True
dtype: bool

s[s].index

Int64Index([0, 5, 7, 9, 10], dtype='int64', name='index')
```